# Transformar uma frase em lista de letras de cada palavra e depois calcular a soma dos números alfabéticos dessas letras

Tags: python

Preciso transformar uma frase em lista de letras de cada palavra e depois calcular a soma dos números alfabéticos dessas letras.

Ex: "joao da silva pinto"

```
nome=input('Digite seu nome completo: ').upper().split()

x=0
while x<len(nome):
    nome[x]=list(nome[x])
    x+=1

##nome ficou: [['J', 'O', 'A', 'O'], ['D', 'A'], ['S', 'I', 'L', 'V', 'A'], ['P', 'I', 'N', 'T', 'O']]
```

Com a seguinte função eu consigo uma lista (teste) número alfabético de cada letra:

```
teste=[]
for i in nome:
    for j in i:
        teste.append((ord(j)-ord("A"))+1)

## ficou assim teste= [10, 15, 1, 15, 4, 1, 19, 9, 12, 22, 1, 16, 9, 14, 20, 15]
```

O problema é que eu queria uma lista aninhada onde cada conjunto de número ficasse no índice correspondente ao sobrenome, assim:

```
##teste= [[10,15,1,15],[4,1],[19,9,12,22,1],[16,9,14,20,15]]
```

Comment: Questão interessante.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não precisa criar a lista com as letras para depois transformá-las em números. Você pode fazer essa transformação toda de uma vez:

```
nome = "joao da silva pinto".upper()

lista = []
a = ord("A")
for s in nome.split():
    lista.append([ord(c) - a + 1 for c in s])

print(lista) # [[10, 15, 1, 15], [4, 1], [19, 9, 12, 22, 1], [16, 9, 14, 20, 15]]
```

Eu faço o [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) do nome, e para cada parte do mesmo eu crio uma sub-lista correspondente aos valores daquela parte.

Em seguida adiciono esta sub-lista de valores na lista de resultados.

---

Se quiser, pode trocar o *loop* acima por uma [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=list%20comprehension#list-comprehensions), bem mais sucinta e [*pythônica*](/q/192343/112052):

```
lista = [
    [ ord(c) - a + 1 for c in s ]
    for s in nome.split()
]
```

Obs: repare que a expressão `ord(c) - a + 1 for c in list(s)` também é uma *list comprehension*, fica bem mais sucinto que fazer outro `for` dentro do `for` mais externo. Mas obviamente você pode fazer assim também:

```
lista = []
for s in nome.split():
    sublista = []
    for c in s:
        sublista.append(ord(c) - a + 1)
    lista.append(sublista)
```

---

Você disse que queria calcular a soma de cada sub-lista. Nesse caso, em vez de criar as sub-listas, basta usar [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) para somar os valores:

```
lista = [
    sum(ord(c) - a + 1 for c in s)
    for s in nome.split()
]

print(lista) # [41, 5, 63, 74]
```

Ou, se não quiser usar a *list comprehension* para construir a lista:

```
lista = []
for s in nome.split():
    lista.append(sum(ord(c) - a + 1 for c in s))
```

E claro que você também poderia fazer a soma manualmente:

```
lista = []
for s in nome.split():
    soma = 0
    for c in s:
        soma += ord(c) - a + 1
    lista.append(soma)
```

---

**Se** quiser mesmo transformar a lista de letras nos seus respectivos números, aí ficaria assim:

```
# pode usar seu código mesmo para gerar esta lista de letras
letras = [['J', 'O', 'A', 'O'], ['D', 'A'], ['S', 'I', 'L', 'V', 'A'], ['P', 'I', 'N', 'T', 'O']]
numeros = []
for sublista in letras:
    n = []
    for c in sublista:
        n.append(ord(c) - a + 1)
    numeros.append(n)
```

Ou, usando *list comprehension*:

```
numeros = [ list(map(lambda c: ord(c) - a + 1, sublista)) for sublista in letras ]
```

Aqui usei [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) para transformar cada elemento das sub-listas no respectivo número.

E se quiser calcular a soma:

```
numeros = []
for sublista in letras:
    soma = 0
    for c in sublista:
        soma += ord(c) - a + 1
    numeros.append(soma)
print(numeros)

# ou, com list comprehension
numeros = [ sum(map(lambda c: ord(c) - a + 1, sublista)) for sublista in letras ]
```

Comment: Genial! Obrigado!

Comment: @RenanDeCastroReis Se a resposta resolveu o seu problema, vc pode aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema. Não esqueça que [**vc também pode votar**](/help/privileges/vote-up) na resposta, caso tenha achado  útil.

Answer (score -1):

eu fiz esse código e acho que deu certo.

```
nome = input('Digite seu nome completo: ').upper().split()
```

```
tudo = list()
for i in nome:
    if i != i[0]:
        tudo.append(palavra)
    palavra.clear()
    for j in i:
        palavra.append((ord(j)-ord("A"))+1)
print(tudo)
```

Comment: Obrigado, Marcelo. Mas não deu certo. ele repetiu o primeiro (versão numérica) nome em todas as listas